# G-WAN C script with hiredis example

Tags: shared-libraries, g-wan

Has anyone integrated redis with a G-WAN C script? I can't seem to get the properly linkage of the libraries of hiredis working on centos linux.

Will appreciate if someone has done that... (preferable on a docker container example)

Thanks

Comment: I was wrote https://github.com/fatihky/gwan-redis-async

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions (redis, docker) in your question and most of the problems you are facing probably come from the fact that you need to understand more about the way C/C++ compilers link libraries and how libraries are registered and searched in the system.

There are two articles in the G-WAN FAQs detailling [how to link libraries](http://gwan.ch/faq#use_libraries) with G-WAN scripts and how to [properly install libraries in the system](http://gwan.ch/faq#new_libraries).

G-WAN comes with many examples showing how to link with C libraries such as SQLite, Cairo, MySQL, etc. so believe me, you don't need a linking example, you need to check how your library is installed and how you can load it and resolve its symbols from G-WAN.

Comment: You are right. I'm using CentOS and have problem linking some libraries even after ldconfig. Seems like I can't get it right I will try again in a few days and get back here.
I wish there is some instructions available on installation and linking redis and ssdb so I can start to write a decent program with G-Wan. I understand G-Wan's strength now... it's flexibility and speed.